# matlab code regarding grouping of elements

Tags: matlab

So i have this code which goes like:

```
a = 51.50:0.001:51.51;
b = -2.55:0.238:-0.17;
c = 1000

p1 = [a(:),b(:)]
```

Now if you run this code, it'll give column 1 with all the 'a' components and column 2 with 'b' components. Is it possible anyway to get matlab to give me back the components like:

p1 = (a1,b1)
p2 = (a2,b2)
..... and so on where a1 and a2 are first components of a and same for b. means in sets of twos. like x and y components.

Another thing, also for the same code, is it possible to insert a third column, lets say 'c', with all the components as 1000?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First question: once you have your `p1` variable, simply use `p1(1,:)`, `p1(2,:)` etc.

Second question: use

```
c = 1000*ones(1,size(p1,1)); %// define vector c as needed, with appropriate size
p1 = [p1, c(:)];
```

Comment: for the first one, is there an automated command to list all without writing them all down?

Comment: @user3276258 I'm not sure I understand. If you type `p1` at the command window it will show all values, with `a` in column 1 and `b` in column 2

Comment: for the second part you could also also just do `p1(:, end+1) = 1000`